# In iOS In App Purchase, is it possible a user get charged, and app receives a timeout?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am using `StoreKit`. I need to know if it is possible a user get charged and the app get "timeout" or any network error from `StoreKit`.

Maybe I need to check the receipt every time I start my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible**

There are ways to recover from such a scenario though. Have a look into this technical note from Apple:

[In-App Purchase Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html)